# Writing a LaunchDaemon for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, daemon, launchd

[JAILBROKE]
I've googled, but i can't find any guides on how to write a LaunchDaemon. This is for the iPhone, so it'll be in Objective-C. I know Objective-C well, i just need some kind of guide to get me started.

I know how to write the daemon .plist, what i mean is- how to write the binary that the .plist runs, eg: usr/bin/myBinary

Would it be the same as usual?
    int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can't unless you jailbreak your iPhone.

Once jailbroken, any executable file specified in the plist would be run. You can use whatever methods to write it. Read [launchd.plist documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html). There's no contract between the system and the daemon in addition to what's written there. Write it as you wish. Even a script (not a combined binary) should work.

Comment: I'm talking Jailbreak here, sorry i should have said, i'll amend it.